# After insert update current custom object fields with standard object

Tags: trigger

I m new to salesforce.i have custom object **Lease__c** , i wanna update the account name and owner field from opportunity.In lease__c i have lookup for opportunity field.how to write trigger for Lease__c for after insert

Comment: why would you want to go with a trigger for this. You could achieve this using formula or a workflow field update.

Comment: Hi Harini, Welcome to SFSE. you can refer this Trailhead module to get started with triggers https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/apex_triggers and if you got stuck after trying on your own, you can post with details on where you need help further.

Comment: @ShaileshDeshpande is right,  use triggers for complicated stuff like batch processes, or multi-object decision trees. Try to create workflow, which updates fields after record creation.

Answer (score 1):

On custom object `Lease__c`, create two new formula fields. These are called cross-object formula fields.

```
Account_Name__c with formula expression = opportunity__r.account.name
Opportunity_Owner__c with formula expression = opportunity__r.owner.name
```

If the Lease's opportunity owner changes, any reports or views on that Lease object will automatically pick up the new owner name; same if the Lease's Opportunity's Account name changes (or even if the Opportunity is switched to a different Account).